# Where to find language in GA4 real time reports?

Tags: google-analytics

Is there a way to know what language a user is using on their browser in real time?  Or is there a way to know what language of the website they are viewing my website in real time?  I can't seem to find any mention of language in GA4 real time reports.  Here's screenshot:

[image]

What am I doing wrong?